# How to change the CSS on the last clicked div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating a messaging inbox and would like to have the selected message (div) change colour when selected.  I have done this but I am not sure how to set the div back to the original colour once another message (div) is selected. This is what I have so far but each message will get the selected class.

```
<script>
function getmessage(str)  {    
$('#mb'+str).removeClass('Message-Background');
    $('#mb'+str).addClass('Message-Background-Selected');
     // alert('#mb'+str);
//   var lastmb = $('#mb'+str);
     $('#mt'+str).removeClass('Message-Title');
    $('#mt'+str).addClass('Message-Title-Selected');
    //var lastmr = $('#mt'+str);
    $('#mprev'+str).removeClass('Message-Text');
    $('#mprev'+str).addClass('Message-Text-Selected'); 
}
</script>


<div id="mb1" class="Message-Background" style="border-left:#000 solid 4px;">
<div id="mt1" class="Message-Title" onclick="getmessage(this.id)" style="float:left;">
Title 1
</div>
<div id="mprev1" class="Message-Text" style="float:left;">
Message 1
</div>
</div>
<div id="mb2" class="Message-Background" style="border-left:#000 solid 4px;">
<div id="mt2" class="Message-Title" onclick="getmessage(this.id)" style="float:left;">
Title 2
</div>
<div id="mprev2" class="Message-Text" style="float:left;">
Message 2
</div>
</div>
<div id="mb3" class="Message-Background" style="border-left:#000 solid 4px;">
<div id="mt3" class="Message-Title" onclick="getmessage(this.id)" style="float:left;">
Title 3
</div>
<div id="mprev3" class="Message-Text" style="float:left;">
Message 3
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `.toggleClass()` instead to remove the class and then add the new class, and attach it into the `.on('click'...);` event of your `div`. http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: I looked at that but its not that I'm toggling the same message selected then unselected I need to change the last clicked on div

Comment: If I understood what you want, you have some divs, with some messages. Then, when you click a div, it changes his class to change his background and if you click another time, it changes to the 'default' class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to change multiple elements I would set the click on the ".message-background" and toggle a class there that effects all of the css within it.

Javascript:

```
$(".message-background").click(function() {
    $(".message-background").removeClass('Message-Background-Selected');
    $(this).addClass('Message-Background-Selected');
});
```

Now the elements within the message-background can just inherit the selected state from it.
CSS:

```
.Message-Background-Selected {
    border:1px solid red;
}
.Message-Background-Selected .Message-Title {
    color:red;
}
.Message-Background-Selected .Message-Text {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks have tried this but the background colour changes on the messge title text not the whole div background...

Comment: Thanks jardiohead I have got it working using this method. http://jsfiddle.net/4dZpU/5/ .

Answer (score 7):

Just make a function:

```
 $("div").click(function() {
      $("div").removeClass('Message-Text-Selected');
      $(this).addClass('Message-Text-Selected'); 
  });
```

You can also use `toggleClass`

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hwgTr/

Comment: Thanks tried this but it will change the message text of all the messages as its applied to all div's.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done like this too:

```
 $("div").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('message-selected').siblings().removeClass('message-selected'); 
  });
```